# If $\sqrt{1-x^2}+\sqrt{1-y^2}=a(x-y)$, prove that $\frac{dy}{dx}=\sqrt{\frac{1-y^2}{1-x^2}}$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

> If $\sqrt{1-x^2}+\sqrt{1-y^2}=a(x-y)$, prove that $\frac{dy}{dx}=\sqrt{\frac{1-y^2}{1-x^2}}$

**My Attempt**
$$
\frac{-2x}{2\sqrt{1-x^2}}-\frac{2y}{2\sqrt{1-y^2}}.\frac{dy}{dx}=a-a\frac{dy}{dx}\\
\implies \frac{dy}{dx}\bigg[a-\frac{y}{\sqrt{1-y^2}}\bigg]=a+\frac{x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\\
\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{a\sqrt{1-x^2}+x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}.\frac{\sqrt{1-y^2}}{a\sqrt{1-y^2}+x}=\sqrt{\frac{1-y^2}{1-x^2}}.\frac{a\sqrt{1-x^2}+x}{a\sqrt{1-y^2}-y}
$$

How do I poceed further and find the derivative ?

Comment: you can eliminate $a$ with your first equation!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After my comment you will get $$a\sqrt{1-x^2}+x=\frac{1-xy+\sqrt{1-x^2}\sqrt{1-y^2}}{x-y}$$ and
$$a\sqrt{1-y^2}-y=\frac{1-xy+\sqrt{1-x^2}\sqrt{1-y^2}}{x-y}$$ and you will get the desired result!

Comment: How did you find this! I liked both your and JJ's answer, but how you found this?

Comment: Hm, intuition and the result containes no $a$, these are the reasons

Answer (score 5):

Both $x,y\in[-1,1]$. So, $x=\sin\theta$ and $y=\sin\phi$ for some $\displaystyle \theta,\phi\in\left[\frac{-\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2}\right]$. Note that $\cos\theta, \cos\phi\ge0$.

We have $$\cos\theta+\cos\phi=a(\sin\theta-\sin\phi)$$

So, $$2\cos\frac{\theta+\phi}{2}\cos\frac{\theta-\phi}{2}=2a\cos\frac{\theta+\phi}{2}\sin\frac{\theta-\phi}{2}$$

$\displaystyle \tan\frac{\theta-\phi}{2}=\frac{1}{a}$ is a constant. So, $\displaystyle \frac{d\phi}{d\theta}=1$.

$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{\cos\phi}{\cos\theta}\frac{d\phi}{d\theta}=\frac{\sqrt{1-y^2}}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$$

Comment: you beat me to it ! +1

Comment: Good answer but how can we say $y\in [0,1]$? $y\in [-1,0]$ according to plot for positive $a$

Comment: @$y\in[-1,1]$.  But $\cos\phi=\sqrt{1-y^2}\in[0,1]$. This is true as $\phi \in[\frac{-\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2}]$.

Comment: I have a typo here. Will edit it

Comment: Please, take a look to my solution, in the spirit of yours.

Answer (score 4):

HINT :
There is no parameter $a$ in the formula to be proved. So, first transform the initial equation into an equation where $a$ will be immediately eliminated by differentiation:
$$\frac{\sqrt{1-x^2}+\sqrt{1-y^2}}{x-y}=a$$
Differentiate and simplify.

Comment: @KingTut just do the differentiation from the form of the equation stated by@JJacquelin u'll get the final answer. So my original post is certainly not incorrect.

Comment: @ss ok let me check the error. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Move $a(x-y)$ to the LHS to make $F(x,y)=0$. Then:
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=-\frac{F'_x}{F'_y}=-\frac{-\frac{x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}-a}{-\frac{y}{\sqrt{1-y^2}}+a}=\frac{a\sqrt{1-x^2}+x}{a\sqrt{1-y^2}-y}\cdot \frac{\sqrt{1-y^2}}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}=\frac{\sqrt{1-y^2}}{\sqrt{1-x^2}},$$
because:
$$\begin{align}&\frac{a\sqrt{1-x^2}+x}{a\sqrt{1-y^2}-y}= \\
&1 \iff a(\sqrt{1-x^2}-\sqrt{1-y^2})=-(x+y) \iff a(y^2-x^2)= \\
&-(x+y)(\sqrt{1-x^2}+\sqrt{1-y^2}) \iff a(x-y)=\\
&\sqrt{1-x^2}+\sqrt{1-y^2}.\end{align}$$

Answer (score 1):

Let us remark that the looked for differential equation can be written under the form

$$\frac{dx}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}=\frac{dy}{\sqrt{1-y^2}}\tag{1}$$

involving solutions of the form :

$$-\arccos(x)=-\arccos(y)+a\tag{2}$$

otherwise said with cartesian equation :

$$y=\cos(\arccos(x)-a)\tag{3}$$

where $a$ is any real.

Setting $\alpha=\arccos(x)$ in (3), we get the equivalent parametric equations :

$$\begin{cases}x&=&\cos(\alpha)\\y&=&\cos(\alpha-a)\end{cases}\tag{4}$$

in which we recognize that we are working with **elliptical arcs**, as shown on the graphical representation of the family of curves $C_a$ displayed below (we have to pay attention to the domains of variables $x$ and $y$ : in general we will not have the whole ellipses as solutions but arcs of them).

From (4), it is easy to establish a connection with relationship:

$$\sqrt{1-x^2}+\sqrt{1-y^2}=a(x-y)$$

(in the spirit of the solution given by @CY Aries).

[image]

*Fig. 1:Curves $C_a$ for $a=-\pi$ to $a=\pi$ with step $\pi/8$ (progressively changing from blue to red). The curves are elliptical arcs with two degenerate cases (straight lines).*